# Dart pub.dev showing 'No Valid SDK'

Tags: dart

I've just published an update to Dart a package that I'm working on.

https://pub.dev/packages/dshell

The latest updated doesn't seem to have any significant changes to the pubspec however pub.dev is reporting an error:

https://pub.dev/packages/dshell#flags

`No valid SDK. (-20 points)`

I've google this error and the associated description:

`The analysis could not detect a valid SDK that can use this package.`

I can't find any useful references to either message and I'm at a loss as to what might now be causing the problem.

The problem does appear to coincide with pub.dev moving to Dart 2.7 so maybe this is a bug in pana?

Any ideas on even where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/pana/issues/591). Unfortunately, I think the only thing you can do at this point is wait until it gets fixed.